# How interpret a barcode pdf417 from a pistol of barcode 2D?

Tags: 2d, barcode

For example the [barcode](http://www.google.cl/imgres?imgurl=http://www.omniplanar.com/_upload/CodePics/PDF417/PDF417-USPS.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.omniplanar.com/PDF417-2D-Barcode.php&usg=__5eyBYSFp9iT6FlHpJYtkqqoWBqM=&h=272&w=502&sz=88&hl=es&start=0&sig2=l2BZLqywZdFNVR80EGaOqA&zoom=1&tbnid=coAsr-DhfUXCiM%3a&tbnh=118&tbnw=217&ei=BxLGTY6KJqTk0QHg1qm9CA&prev=/search?q=barcode%2b2d%2bpdf417&hl=es&sa=X&biw=1280&bih=656&tbm=isch&prmd=ivns&itbs=1&iact=hc&vpx=124&vpy=288&dur=1203&hovh=165&hovw=305&tx=219&ty=71&page=1&ndsp=15&ved=1t:429,r:5,s:0) in a document of identification, reading with [this pistol](http://www.fenway.cl/producto.aspx?id=17) and interpret in a software in any language

Answer (score 0):

Usually the output from a barcode scanner is the text in the barcode followed by a ENTER. So to simulate your software should (simply put) be able to accept input from the keyboard followed by ENTER.